# Generic base class constructor

Tags: c#, generics

Using this generic base class:

```
public abstract class Logic<U> where U : class
{
    protected U m_provider;
    public Logic(U provider)
    {
        m_provider = provider;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a base test class for unit test:

```
public class LogicBaseTest<T, U> where T : Logic <U>, new()  where U: class
{
    protected T m_logic;
    protected U m_provider;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public virtual void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        m_provider = (U)Substitute.For<IInterface>();

        m_logic = new T(m_provider);
    }
}
```

It complains on the constructor, it requests for the new() constrain but when I add it then it complains that the constructor cannot take parameters.

I could add a method to populate the provider but I'm wondering whether it could be done in the constructor.

Comment: The problem is that with `where T : Logic<U>, new()` you're saying "So, whatever type T is, it must inherit from `Logic` and the generic parameter must be `U`. Also, `T` needs to have a public parameterless constructor" but your `Logic<U>` class alone already violates the `new()` constraint, the solution is either remove the `new()` constraint or add a public parameterless constructor to `Logic`

Comment: I added the new() constraint because it complained that "Cannot create an instance of the variable 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint."

Comment: I'm wondering how you would ever instantiate that test-class. Which test-framework are you using?

Comment: Using NUnit and NSubstitute. I am able to get it working by not calling the generic ctor and instead calling in the sub class with the actual type. But I'm wondering whether it would be possible to get that generic ctor to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have two problems here:

1. LogicBaseTest needs to know how to instantiate a `Logic<U>`.
2. `Logic<U>` requires a `U` in the constructor.

My proposed solution to it is to pass a factory delegate into the base test class and remove the `new()` requirement. Then your setup can construct the `Logic` class using the factory:

```cs
public class LogicBaseTest<T, U> 
    where T : Logic<U>
    where U: class
{

    protected readonly Func<U, T> _factory;

    public LogicBaseTest(Func<U, T> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public virtual void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        m_provider = (U)Substitute.For<IInterface>();
        m_logic = _factory(m_provider);
    }
}
```

In the derived test class you just have to tell the base class how to new up a `Logic<U>`:

```cs
public class DerivedTest : LogicBaseTest<Logic<MyUType>, MyUType>
{
    public DerivedTest()
        : this(u => new Logic<MyUType>(u))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll go with the factory, it looks somehow similar to my last comment on removing the ctor from base class and calling the subclass ctor from subtest.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down your generic constraint into plain English

```
where T : Logic<U>, new()
```

This means

> The type of `T` needs to inherit from `Logic`, the generic type parameter must be `U` and have a public, parameterless, constructor

But the problem is that `Logic` by itself already breaks that constraint. Now, how do we fix this? There are multiple ways

1. Use a "factory function" to instantiate your `m_logic` alongside removing the `new` constraint (see [DiplomacyNotWar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72443772/9363973))
2. Remove the `new()` constraint and use something like [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-6.0) instead to instantiate your `Logic` class
3. Add a parameterless constructor to `Logic` and configure your `m_provider` some other way
4. Move instantiation of `m_logic` into the unit test itself (maybe add a helper method if you need to create the same `Logic` for a ton of unit tests)
5. Research if your unit testing framework supports some form of Dependency Injection and inject everything you need

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a generic type constraint such as `where T : new(U)`.
Instead, you can use a Factory.

```cs
public interface IFactory<out TObject, in TProvider>
{
    public TObject Create(TProvider provider);
}
```

then use it in your base test

```cs
public class LogicBaseTest<T, U> where T : Logic <U> where U: class // remove new()
{
    // fields

    private readonly IFactory<T, U> _factory;

    public LogicBaseTest(IFactory<T, U> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public virtual void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        m_provider = (U)Substitute.For<IInterface>();
       
        m_logic = _factory.Create(m_provider);
    }
}
```

## Example

```cs
public class Logic1Provider
{
    
}

public class Logic1Factory : IFactory<Logic1, Logic1Provider>
{
    public Logic1 Create(Logic1Provider provider)
    {
        return new Logic1(provider);
    }
}

public class Logic1 : Logic<Logic1Provider>
{
    public Logic1(Logic1Provider provider) : base(provider)
    {
    }

    public void DoDomeLogic()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

```cs
var factory = new Logic1Factory();
var baseTest = new LogicBaseTest<Logic1, Logic1Provider>(factory);
```